# create superscript jqeryui button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I am trying to replicate a superscript icon in text within a jquery ui button. I have tried several combos but everything screws up the button. It will align incorrectly within a buttonset().

css

```
.superscript{float: left; font-size:xx-small; vertical-align:top;} 
.floatleft{ float: left;}
```

js

```
$("<a/>",{
href : "#",
html : '<span class="floatleft">x</span><span class="superscript">2</span>',
}).button();
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use `float: left;`. Just remove it. See the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the HTML `<sup>` tag instead of a span?

Comment: That is a good point. I don't suppose I can shift it up can I?

Comment: ah to easy! end of the day here I am over-complicating things!

Comment: This is the first time that I see a question is accepted as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, if you give `float: left;` it affects the `vertical-align: top;` because, `vertical-align` can be given only to inline elements and when you `float`, it becomes a block level element.

Small change in your CSS.

```
.superscript {font-size: xx-small; vertical-align: top;} 
.floatleft {float: left;}
```

#### That should work. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UThnc/1/).